# Verifying PEP8 in iPython notebook code

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pep8

Is there an easy way to check that iPython notebook  code, while it's being written, is compliant with PEP8?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, I'm using:

`conttest "jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --stdout --to script | flake8 - --ignore=W391"`

- `conttest` reruns when saving changes to the notebook
- `flake8 -` tells flake8 to take input from stdin
- `--ignore=W391` - this is because the output of `jupyter nbconvert` seems to always have a "blank line at end of file", so I don't want flake8 to complain about that.

I'm having a problem with markdown cells (whose line lengths may legitimately be quite long, though): [ignore markdown cells in `jupyter nbconvert` with `--to script`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423380/ignore-markdown-cells-in-jupyter-nbconvert-with-to-script).

Comment: This will result in false positives if the IPython notebook contains magics. I'd suggest `conttest "nbqa flake8 notebook.ipynb --extend-ignore=W391"` instead. This will also ignore the markdown cells

Answer (score 45):

Make sure you've the module `pycodestyle` or `flake8` to be able to check your code against the style guides. Then enable the magic function by using the `pycodestyle_magic` module ([github repo](https://github.com/mattijn/pycodestyle_magic)):

```
pip install flake8 pycodestyle_magic
```

- first load the magic in a Jupyter Notebook cell:

`%load_ext pycodestyle_magic`

- and then turn on the magic to do compliance checking for each cell using:

`%pycodestyle_on` or `%flake8_on`

depending against which style guide you want to check.

[image]

To turn off the auto-compliance-checking run:

`%pycodestyle_off` or `%flake8_off`

Comment: rephrased the first sentence, glad it's helpful

Comment: Does this not work anymore? I get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycodestyle_magic'" even though it's installed.

Comment: Good thing, but seems like it multiply outputs an error message and does not cleaning before cell is executed. Is there a way to get rid of multiple error messages?

Comment: @KOHTPOJIEP could you file an issue at the GitHub page of `pycodestyle_magic`? Thanks!

Comment: This is the new best answer. Exactly what I have been looking for

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer works on Google Colaboratory.  The packages installed fine, but I'm getting a strange error trying to run either `%flake8_on` or `%pycodestyle_off`: `TypeError: auto_run_flake8() missing 1 required positional argument: 'result'` and `TypeError: auto_run_pycodestyle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'result'`.

Comment: This works fine, what about auto edit the code in cell?

Comment: What about disabling checks? I tried to add a tox.ini but seems like it's ignored.

Comment: Looks like pycodestyle_magic is now unmaintained

Comment: This has not worked for me either when attempting to run %pycodestyle_on or %flake8_on .  Returing an example error message:

Error in callback <bound method VarWatcher.auto_run_pycodestyle of <pycodestyle_magic.VarWatcher object at 0x000001D8E3361908>> (for post_run_cell):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: auto_run_pycodestyle() missing 1 required positional argument: 'result'

Answer (score 10):

Install the pep8 extension for ipython notebook using the following command :

```
%install_ext https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiggyF/notebooks/master/pep8_magic.py
```

Refer [the official docs](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Extensions-Index#pep8) for more info.

After that use the `%%pep8` Cell magic function to check your particular cell for pep8 styling.

Note that this has to be put inside every cell for which pep8 checking needs to be enforced.

Refer [this example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/SiggyF/notebooks/blob/master/styleguide.ipynb).

Comment: install_ext has been deprecated and removed. Extensions now need to be published on PyPI and installed with pip.

Comment: pep8 is deprecated and extensions now needs to be published on PyPi, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204361/2459096 or srcoll down

Comment: I was unable to get this to work and as per @Mattijn +1 this approach is no longer viable.

Comment: No longer viable answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using [nbQA](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA) for this:

```
pip install -U nbqa flake8
conttest "nbqa flake8 notebook.ipynb"
```

as it'll skip markdown cells and robustly handle IPython magics.

Issues with the other answers are:

- "jupyter nbconvert" won't be robust to magics
- `pycodestyle_magic` is unfortunately no longer maintained (last commit is from 2019)
- `install_ext` is deprecated

---

disclaimer: I'm the author of nbQA

Answer (score 1):

I like keeping my notebooks tidy using the combination of the [`black` linter](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [`pre-commit` git hooks](https://pre-commit.com/) (to automatically lint with every commit).

```
pip install pre-commit "black[jupyter]"
# <-- create your .pre-commit-config.yaml
pre-commit install
black {source_file_or_directory}
# your notebooks will be linted whenever you commit now
```

For instructions on how to setup your `.pre-commit-config.yaml`, see the [black docs](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/source_version_control.html?highlight=jupyter#version-control-integration)) and [pre-commit docs](https://pre-commit.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could include parts of my script (link below) to see details which code lines need specific PEP8 corrections. You could also runs it independently.

The script includes PEP8 comments into the py file code based on flake8. 
This makes it very easy to immediately jump to the place where the correction of the style is needed.

You can check it here:
https://github.com/Softerec/PEP8-commenter

Comment: Hello! Please write out the specific part of your code that answers the question, don't link to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to free yourself from bugs in the code or program that will pay you too much attention to EPE8, install two correction programs at once.

we install it:

```
pip install nb_black   
pip install flake8 pycodestyle_magic
```

paste into the code at the beginning:

```
%load_ext nb_black
%load_ext pycodestyle_magic 
%pycodestyle_on
```

attention the order is important

Comment: This looks like a good solution. Could you elaborate a little more on what each package is doing, particularly `nb_black`, and why the order matters?