# ignore markdown cells in `jupyter nbconvert` with `--to script`

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

Is it possible to have `jupyter nbconvert ... --to script` ignore markdown cells rather than convert them to comments?

I'm asking because I want to use `flake8` to check the Python code that's generated but I don't want to include the markdown cells (for example, because they are often long lines, and I don't want flake8 to complain about them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the command line argument `PythonExporter.exclude_markdown` that does what you want. To get a list of pep8 errors that just look at the code cells, I run

```sh
jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --stdout --to python --PythonExporter.exclude_markdown=True | flake8 - --ignore=W391
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

Create a template `strip_markdown.tpl`

```
## remove markdown cells
{% extends 'python.tpl'%}
{% block markdowncell -%}
{% endblock markdowncell %}
```

jupyter nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb --to python --template=strip_markdown.tpl

Answer (score 0):

> I'm asking because I want to use flake8 to check the Python code that's generated

You can do this directly with [nbqa](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA) :

```
$ nbqa flake8 my_notebook.ipynb --extend-ignore=E203,E302,E305,E703
my_notebook.ipynb:cell_3:1:1: F401 'import pandas as pd' imported but unused
```

It also works as a pre-commit hook, see https://nbqa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pre-commit.html