# Installing a jupyter notebook extension

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipython-magic

I tried without success to install some extensions to jupyter notebook and can't figure out how to do it.
So basically I would like to have pep8 code checking in my notebook.
I checked this post:
[Verifying PEP8 in iPython notebook code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126853/verifying-pep8-in-ipython-notebook-code)

However `%install_ext` is deprecated so instead I used

```
jupyter nbextension install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SiggyF/notebooks/master/pep8_magic.py --user
```

So I get:

```
Copying: /tmp/tmpw74yl7m2/pep8_magic.py -> /home/louis/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/pep8_magic.py

To initialize this nbextension in the browser every time the notebook (or other app) loads:

          jupyter nbextension enable <the entry point> --user
```

From now on I could not get it working.
I tried:

```
~$ jupyter nbextension enable pep8_magic.py --user
Enabling notebook extension pep8_magic.py...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X pep8_magic.py
```

Without success.

Can someone explain a simple method to get it working and what I missed about jupyter extensions ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

I manually copied the file from the link and then added to /.ipython/extensions (or /nbextensions) and loaded in the notebook: `%load_ext pep8_magic`

Currently testing but looks fine to me