# Using Pylint in Ipython (Jupyter-Notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pylint, flake8

I want to run Pylint or any equivalent while using Jupyter-Notebook. Is there a way to install and run Pylint this way?

Comment: refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126853/verifying-pep8-in-ipython-notebook-code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**pycodestyle** is an equivalent of `pylint` for Jupyter Notebook which is able to check your code against the `PEP8` style guide.

First, you need to install the `pycodestyle` in `jupyter notebook` by typing this command,

```
!pip install pycodestyle pycodestyle_magic
```

Run this command in a cell of jupyter notebook.
After successful installation, you have to load the magic in a Jupyter Notebook cell like this,

```
%load_ext pycodestyle_magic
```

Then, you have to use `pycodestyle` in a cell in which you want to investigate your code against `PEP8` standards.

Below are some examples for more and clear understanding,

```
%%pycodestyle
a=1
```

Output: `pycodestyle` will give you this message,

```
2:2: E225 missing whitespace around operator
```

Another example,

```
%%pycodestyle
def square_of_number(
     num1, num2, num3, 
     num4):
    return num1**2, num2**2, num3**2, num4**2
```

Output:

```
2:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 0
3:23: W291 trailing whitespace
```

Comment: Pylint does a lot more than just check the style, a lot of people would want to use Pylint for it's static analysis error detection capabilities, can this library do that as well?

Comment: @shawn, I didn't upvote this answer and didn't award the bounty I placed because it doesn't actually answer the question regarding Pylint.

Comment: unfortunately, it looks like `pycodestyle_magic` is no longer maintained, the last commit is from 2019

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you consider the [nbQA](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA) tool:

```
pip install nbqa pylint
nbqa pylint my_notebook.ipynb
```

Besides `pylint`, `nbqa` makes it easy to run several other formatter and linter tools and is easy to integrate into your development workflow via their dedicated [pre-commit hooks](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA#pre-commit).

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question more specifically in regards to `pylint`. One relatively simple way to achieve that in a development / ci environment (i.e. command line) is to convert the notebook to Python and then run the linting.

Let's assume you have notebooks in the `./notebooks` folder and you have the `jupyter` and `pylint` command in the path, you could run the following:

```
jupyter nbconvert \
    --to=script \
    --output-dir=/tmp/converted-notebooks/ \
    ./notebooks/*.ipynb
pylint /tmp/converted-notebooks/*.py
```

You might want to configure pylint, as the notebook style is slightly different to a general Python module.

Some rules that you might want to disable:

- pointless-statement
- expression-not-assigned
- trailing-newlines
- wrong-import-position
- redefined-outer-name
- invalid-name

It also appears that the maximum number of characters in a cell (before horizontal scrolling) is `116` but that might depend on other factors.

(These options can for example be configured using the `--max-line-length` and `--disable` pylint arguments, or via the `.pylintrc` file)

Answer (score 4):

The **JupyterLab** extension **jupyterlab-lsp** supports pylint (but pylint is disabled by default):

https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server/issues/171#event-6236223765

```
pip install jupyterlab-lsp
pip install 'python-lsp-server[all]'
```

---

Here is my config for the **LanguageServer** tab under Settings => Advanced Settings Editor, enabling pylint:

```
{  
    "language_servers": {
        "pyright": {
            "serverSettings": {
                "python.analysis.useLibraryCodeForTypes": true
            }
        },
        "pylsp": {
            "serverSettings": {
                "pylsp": {
                    "plugins": {
                        "pydocstyle": {
                          "enabled": true
                        },
                        "pyflakes": {
                          "enabled": false
                        },
                        "flake8": {
                          "enabled": true
                        },
                        "pylint": {
                          "enabled": true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: For updated configuration see related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77050674/2876079

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to reformat a notebook using black or yapf using Jupyter-lsp?

Answer (score 0):

In case you opt for using `nbqa` but you happen to have notebooks using `pyspark` as framework (instead of `python`), the following command will fail to recognize your notebooks:

```bash
nbqa pylint **/*.ipynb
```

The reason is that .ipynb files using pyspark have this metadata in the body:

```json
"metadata": {
   "name": "pyspark"
  }
```

which prevents nbqa for recognizing it as python type. The solution is to simply substitute the value of "pyspark" with "python", here is a shell script that does it (you might need to install `jq`):

```bash
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.ipynb");
  do jq '.metadata.language_info.name="python"' "$i" > "$i".ipynb;
  nbqa pylint "$i".ipynb -f colorized --fail-under=7;
  rm "$i".ipynb;
done;
```