# Is there a python style checker that works on notebooks in google colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, spell-checking, pylint

Style checkers are a great tool when it comes to organizing your notebooks. I am working in [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/)  recently and noticed that I couldn't find anything online on a style checker in google colab.

In terms of Python style guide checkers, I found that using Spyder as an IDE one could use [Pylint](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/) and in terms of Jupiter notebooks I found [a post of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358327/using-pylint-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook) where one suggested using [pycodestyle](https://pypi.org/project/pycodestyle/) as

```
!pip install pycodestyle pycodestyle_magic
%load_ext pycodestyle_magic
```

but this did not work and gave a long error message

```
   17 import copy
     18 import pycodestyle as pycodestyle_module
---> 19 from flake8.api import legacy as flake8_module
     20 from contextlib import redirect_stdout
     21 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flake8'
```

##Summary##
So **to summarize how can one import and use a style checker in google colab** . Please may you also provide an example of the lines that you may have used in your notebook that worked?

Answer (score 1):

This DOES work in colab, but you have to manually install flake8 too:

```
!pip install pycodestyle pycodestyle_magic
!pip install flake8
%load_ext pycodestyle_magic
```

Then add %%pycodestyle at the top of any cell you want linted:

[image: screenshot of pycodestyle linting working correctly in colab]

Comment: How could I run the linter for the entire notebook? This fix works for me, but I don't like to insert a magic in each cell.

Comment: How I can config max-line-length for flake8?

Answer (score -1):

You can install flake8 for notebooks

```
!pip install flake8-nb
!flake8_nb example_notebook.ipynb
```

[flake8-nb](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-nb/)

Comment: Where could one find the .ipynb in Google Colab? I think the OP referred specifically to Colab.