# How to use Pylint or other linters with Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pylint, linter

Is it possible to have a linter inside of a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Related SO question on JupyterLab:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71495554/2876079

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Yes it is possible
- You can install `pycodestyle`  for Jupyter Notebook which is similar to `pylint`.
  You can use the below commands from inside a Jupyter Notebook shell:

```
# install
!pip install pycodestyle pycodestyle_magic


# load
%load_ext pycodestyle_magic


# use
%%pycodestyle
def square_of_number(
     num1, num2, num3, 
     num4):
    return num1**2, num2**2, num3*

# Output
2:1: E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 0
3:23: W291 trailing whitespace
```

- Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358327/using-pylint-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook) question out for more details. My answer is inspired by the answers in the link.
- Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126853/verifying-pep8-in-ipython-notebook-code) question for more similar linters and solutions.

Comment: This code is not maintained anymore. It is now raising errors that haven't been solved.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - you can run any standard Python code quality tool on a Jupyter Notebook using [nbQA](https://github.com/nbQA-dev/nbQA)

e.g.:

```
pip install -U nbqa pylint
nbqa pylint notebook.ipynb
```

disclaimer: I"m the author of nbQA

Comment: It is good to point out that nbqa has `typing-extensions` as a dependency.

Comment: no it doesn't, it only requires ipython, tomli, and tokenize-rt. anything else (like typing-extensions) must have been brought in by some other tool

Comment: Maybe pylint requires? I just run that `pip install -U nbqa pylint` snipped, then pip warned me to install `typing-extensions`

Comment: yup, pylint requires it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `black` linter in Jupyter:

```
pip install black "black[jupyter]"
black {source_file_or_directory}
```

If you want to auto-lint your notebooks with a pre-commit hook, you have to replace `id: black` with `id: black-jupyter` ([more info here](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/source_version_control.html?highlight=jupyter#version-control-integration)).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the difference between a *linter* and a *formatter*. "Black" is not a linter, it's a formatter.

Comment: @S.B I know the difference. `black` can do either.

Comment: https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-black-not-detect-syntax-errors-in-my-code

Comment: I stand corrected @S.B , I did misunderstand!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FlakeHell](https://flakehell.readthedocs.io/index.html) to run any number of linters supported by flake8 [on entire notebooks](https://flakehell.readthedocs.io/parsers.html#parsers)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution of JupyterLab instead of JupyterNotebook you might want to use **jupyterlab-lsp with support for pylint**. Also see answer to "duplicate" SO question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71495554/2876079